# We are creating an application like news feed.How to get data from rss feeds and i need to provide webservice through json

Tags: php, json, web-services, codeigniter, rss

We are creating an application like news feed.How to get data from rss feeds and i need to provide webservice through json.I am using php codeigniter as server side scripting.

How to get feeds from different sites and send json response dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot of rss feed jquery plugins out there. That could be a simple and fast to implement solution for a basic need.

For example see [zrrsfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/) (Check the examples).

That's just one rss plugins among many others.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...i want to get rss feeds without using jquery and ajax..is there any alternative?we have tried with google feed api but it doesn't providing image data and description..how can i get complete details using google feed api?

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative to jquery could be php CURL, and an example of printing out the feed onto the screen from curl could happen 1 of two ways, from an RSS source, or as an ATOM source, this of course depends on the source FEED.

More Information about Atom vs RSS can be found here:
https://shafiq2410.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/rss-vs-atom-which-one-is-better/

An Example of integrating BOTH into 1 application could look like this

```
// RSS
function parseRSS($xml)
{
    echo "<strong>".$xml->channel->title."</strong><br />";
    $cnt = count($xml->channel->item);
    for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
    {
        $url    = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
        $title  = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
        $desc = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;

        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>'.$desc.'<br />';
    }
}

// Atom
function parseAtom($xml)
{
    echo "<strong>".$xml->author->name."</strong><br />";
    $cnt = count($xml->entry);
    for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
    {
        $urlAtt = $xml->entry->link[$i]->attributes();
        $url    = $urlAtt['href'];
        $title  = $xml->entry->title;
        $desc   = strip_tags($xml->entry->content);

        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>'.$desc.'<br />';
    }
}

$ch = curl_init("http://domain.com/path/to/rss.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
if(isset($doc->channel))
{
    // Parse as RSS
    parseRSS($doc);
}
if(isset($doc->entry))
{
    // Parse as ATOM
    parseAtom($doc);
}
```

Of course instead of echoing out the results, you could handle them however you needed at this point, being that i dont know your overall goal here, i wanted to at least point you in the CURL direction as an option.

I hope this helps get you started.